# Query MAC address of Powerline Ethernet Adapter

Tags: networking, mac-address

I have a computer connect to the Internet using Powerline Ethernet adapters in this fashion:

{Internet} --- [Router] --- [Powerline Adapter A] +++ [Powerline Adapter B] --- COMPUTER

Where --- is an Ethernet connection, and +++ is the home AC wiring.

From the computer is there a way to query the MAC address of [Powerline Adapter B]?

I am using the following Powerline Adapter: Linksys PLEK500
http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/powerline/PLEK500

These have the MAC address printed on the back of each node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your powerline adapter probably does not have a MAC address at all, because it probably isn't an active Ethernet device; rather it's just a dumb repeater.

Comment: I'm using Linksys PLEK500 powerline adapters and they include a MAC address written on the back of each node. Is there a way to query this? http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/powerline/PLEK500

Comment: Define "query" then; what do you actually want to do?

Comment: Just to clarify; MAC indicates that it's an ethernet device, but not that it runs IP, etc.

Comment: By query I mean retrieve the MAC address from the powerline adapter to the connected PC. I would like to use this to "uniquely" identify the PC (lets assume the PC has no unique identifier itself). Thanks for your help Mark.

Comment: So you want to know the IP address of your downstream powerline adapter? e.g. if you had multiple adapters for multiple computers, determine which one is on which adapter? Hmm. I'm not entirely sure this is possible to be honest.

Comment: OK, but why then does it have a MAC address?

Comment: Probably so that multiple adapters can determine which paired device to listen for. Not really sure.

Comment: Yea, perhaps it's used on the powerline side, as opposed to the Ethernet side.

Comment: Ryan is correct. That is a [P1901](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1901) MAC and has nothing to do with the Ethernet network.

Answer (score 0):

From David Schwartz comment on Mark Henderson's answer, this is not possible:

> [...] That is a [P1901](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1901) MAC and has nothing to do with the Ethernet network.